# Show that if $X$ is a bounded random variable, then its characteristic function is a power series with an infinite radius of convergence.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, power-series, characteristic-functions

> Let $X$ be a bounded real random variable. Show that its characteristic function is a power series whose radius of convergence is equal to infinity.

My attempt: let $\varphi $ be its characteristic function.

We have $$\varphi _X(t) = \mathbb{E}[e^{itX}] = \int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{itX}\mathbb{P}_X(dx) =\int_{\mathbb{R}}\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\frac{(itx)^n}{n!}\mathbb{P}_X(dx)  $$ As $X$ is bounded, by the Beppo-Levi theorem, we can interchange the integral and the sum:
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\frac{(itx)^n}{n!}\mathbb{P}_X(dx)   = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{i^nt^n}{n!}\int _{\mathbb{R}}x^n \mathbb{P}_X(dx) = x \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{(xit)^n }{n! (n+1)}$$
And I am unsure if what I did is sufficient and even correct. Any ideas?

Comment: It is correct.  The integral of the powers of x will always exist because X is bounded.

Comment: I'm not at all an expert so perhaps I am missing something...  Isn't the characteristic function $\varphi$ a function of $t$?  How can $x$ appear in the final answer?  Also it would seem to me $\int _{\mathbb{R}}x^n \mathbb{P}_X(dx) = \mathbb{E}[X^n] = $ the $n$th moment (centered around $0$).

Comment: The last equality doesn't make sense, as antkam pointed out. I would also like to suggest an laternative argument. Using DCT you can verify directly that $z \to Ee^{izX}$ is differentiable at all points of $\mathbb C$; entire functions have power series expansions with infinite radius of convergence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The justification of the exchange of the integral and the series follows from the fact that 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left\lvert\frac{(itx)^n}{n!} \right \rvert\mathbb{P}_X(dx)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{\left\lvert t\right \rvert^n}{n!}\left\lvert x\right\rvert^n \mathbb{P}_X(dx)$$
and if $X$ is bounded by $M$, then 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{\left\lvert t\right \rvert^n}{n!}\left\lvert x\right\rvert^n \mathbb{P}_X(dx)=\int_{ [-M,M ]}\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{\left\lvert t\right \rvert^n}{n!}\left\lvert x\right\rvert^n \mathbb{P}_X(dx) \leqslant \int_{ [-M,M ]}\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{\left\lvert t\right \rvert^n}{n!}M^n \mathbb{P}_X(dx)\leqslant \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{\left\lvert t\right \rvert^n}{n!}M^n,$$
which is finite. This leads to 
$$
\varphi_X(t)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_nt^n,\mbox{ where }a_n :=\frac{i^n}{n!}\mathbb E\left[X^n\right] .                           
$$
Since $\left \lvert a_n \right\rvert\leqslant M^n/n!$, the power series has an infinite radius of convergence.